# uncheck all checbox in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i want to uncheckall checkbox in customlistview.my adapter works fine so on click button

**this is written in my button listener**

```
 for(int i = 0; i<listview.getChildCount();i++)
                    {
                     v = listview.getChildAt(i);
                     CheckBox cv =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checktitle);
                     if(cv.isChecked())
                     {
                         // cv.setChecked(false);
                         //listview.setItemChecked(i, false);
                           toggle(cv);

                     }
```

**in toggle method**

```
 public void toggle(CheckBox v)
         {
                 if (v.isChecked())
                 {
                     v.setChecked(false);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     v.setChecked(true);
                 }
         }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    View view=null;
    Context context;
    ViewHolder holder;    boolean checkAll_flag = false;
    boolean checkItem_flag = false;
    List<CustomDishMenus> dcates=new ArrayList<CustomDishMenus>();
    public customAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.dcates=objects;
    }
     static class ViewHolder {
            protected TextView text;
            protected CheckBox checkbox;
        }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         holder = new ViewHolder();
            final CustomDishMenus ords=dcates.get(position);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayout,parent, false);
                if(convertView!=null){

                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checktitle);

                    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                              int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  
                                dcates.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
                     convertView.setTag(holder);
                        convertView.setTag(R.id.title, holder.text);
                        convertView.setTag(R.id.checktitle, holder.checkbox);
                        } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                }
                  holder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

                    holder.text.setText(dcates.get(position).getDishName());
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(dcates.get(position).isSelected());

                return convertView;
    }
```

the problem with this code in view i get 6 child when i scroll down i get again 6 child ..the childs are the item in listview when scrolling up or down which is shown in view so the items of listview shown is child of listview..so i want all child to uncheck but with this code it is not working please tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple way to uncheck all the children CheckBoxes of a ViewGroup (ListView extends ViewGroup). You'll just want to pass your ListView into this method.

```
private void uncheckAllChildrenCascade(ViewGroup vg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
            ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            uncheckAllChildrenCascade((ViewGroup) v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is where you do:

`CheckBox cv =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checktitle)`;

Your trying to get the checkbox associated with "v", but `findViewById()` doesn't do that.  Instead your just creating a NEW checkbox from your XML.

I think what you want to do is modify the underlying data "dcates" and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Something like:

```
for (CustomDishMenus menu : dcates)
    menu.setSelected(false);

listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter (customAdapter) include a method call `setAllSelected();`

```
setAllSelected () {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        AdapterItem info = this.getItem(i);

        // info (add a boolean in you adapter item to store the state of checkbox i.e. isSelected and mark it to true. )
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your `getView()`. according to state of variable(isSelected), select or deselect the checkbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Steve B i want to reset all listview checkbox so i have a button..and in button listener how can i call the method as u mention uncheckAllChildrenCascade(Viewgroup) but in button listener we have only a view how can i call the method uncheckAllChildrenCascade(ViewGroup v)?Your answer is pretty much clear but how can i call this?

Comment: paul this is in my button listener 
CheckBox cv =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checktitle) this line is written in the button listener and above code is also written in button listener.. setOnClickListener..

Comment: didn't have enough rep to comment until today since you didn't comment on my answer...  so if your still looking at this.  i'm suggesting in my answer that you replace the code in your button listener with the code i provided.