# Change text color, text size (and etc.) for all elements of layout

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to change style of all elements in my layout.

For example, i have list view with elements. I need to change color for all elements in some rows.

---

Another example: i need to change style of all elements of layout by clicking on button (allow user to change theme of application).

How can i do this? Using findViewById is really bad solution, cause of many req to DOM and etc. But I don't see any alternative.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of unchecking all checkboxes, but can be modified to manipulate any property of an element.  You simply need to recursively loop through all children in a viewgroup.

[uncheck all checbox in listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509552/uncheck-all-checbox-in-listview-in-android/14510713#14510713)

Comment: it's good if my hierarchy is not big, but if tree of layouts have a lot childs, it will be slow =/

Comment: sure, in theory, a complex layout tree would be slow. but try it out before you jump to conclusions. i see this assumption quite a bit on SO, and in my experience, i have yet to get into a scenario where quantity of views is a performance issue. and if you do in fact have that many views, you should probably look at implementing a completely different rendering engine (ie OpenGL)